# Whats so great about the new MVC2 areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, areas

Could some one please explain the advantages and disadvantages of using the new MVC2 Areas feature?

I don't understand what is so great about them. If I am adding an admin area to my MVC application why not create a new Admin folder in the main Views and Controllers folder? What does creating an area really get me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Phil Haack says:

> The scenario that areas address is
>   being able to partition your
>   application into discrete areas of
>   functionality. It helps make managing
>   a large application more manageable
>   and allows for creating distinct
>   applets that you can drop into an
>   application.

An admin section wouldn't qualify as an applet as it logically belongs with your application and may even share models with it.

Comment: I still don't get what is so great about areas or a scenario in any of my apps that would benefit from them over the default approach.

The "distinct applet" is interesting, but again hard to imagine entire portions of a site being reused.

Comment: the simplest example is a blog with a merchandise store attached to it.